# Do you have any recommended File templates for resharper for VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, templates, file, resharper

The ones that stick out and make life usefull.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one for a testClass with Nunit support.

```
    Imports Nunit.FrameWork

    Namespace $NAMESPACE$
    ''' 
    ''' A TestClass
    ''' 
    ''' 
     _
    Public Class $CLASSNAME$

#Region " Setup and TearDown "
        ''' 
        ''' Sets up the Tests
        ''' 
        ''' 
         _
        Public Sub Setup()

            End Sub

        ''' 
        ''' Tears down the test. Is executed after the Test is Completed
        ''' 
        ''' 
         _
        Public Sub TearDown()

        End Sub      
#End Region  

#Region " Tests "
                ''' 
        ''' A Test
        ''' 
        ''' 
             _
            Public Sub $Test_Name$()

            End Sub
#End Region

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

MSTest testclass. I like my testclass basic. Not like the one that is created by VS.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

<TestClass()> _
Public Class $ClassName$
    $END$
End Class
```

`$Classname` is "Current file name without extension" macro.